# KeyFeatures for Product implementation

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

i've been trying to implement a new feature on a django ecommerce project that i'm working on. i created a separate model in the models.py file just for key features and i linked this model to the product model using the manytomanyfield method. the problem is that i can't get the data to be output at all. when i try printing it, it just outputs None even when the field is populated.
is there a better and cleaner way to implement this feature??

i've provided code bits below

views.py file

```
class ProductDetail(APIView):
    def get_object(self, category_slug, product_slug):
        try:
            return Product.objects.filter(category__slug=category_slug).get(slug=product_slug)
        except Product.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
        
    def get(self, request, category_slug, product_slug, format=None):
        product = self.get_object(category_slug, product_slug)
        feature = product.key_features
        features_serializer = KeyFeatureSerializer(feature)
        serializer = ProductSerializer(product)
        print(feature)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

models.py file

```
class KeyFeature(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name = 'products', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', blank=True, null=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', blank=True, null=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    key_features = models.ManyToManyField(KeyFeature, related_name='products')
    


    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-date_added',)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
```

serializers.py file

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *

# a serializer allows python data to be converted to json form

class KeyFeatureSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = KeyFeature
        fields = ('id', 'name',) 
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    key_features = KeyFeatureSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'get_absolute_url',
            'description',
            'price',
            'get_image',
            'get_thumbnail',
            'key_features'
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing the *manager* not a `QuerySet`, hence the `None`, you can print this with:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


class ProductDetail(APIView):
    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(
            Product,
            category__slug=self.kwargs['category_slug'],
            slug=self.kwargs['product_slug'],
        )

    def get(self, request, category_slug, product_slug, format=None):
        product = self.get_object()
        feature = product.key_features.all()
        features_serializer = KeyFeatureSerializer(feature, many=True)
        serializer = ProductSerializer(product)
        print(feature)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

It also makes not much sense to call the `KeyFeatureSerializer` itself, since it is a sub-serializer of your `ProductSerializer`. In fact most of the boilerplate code can be removed by using a [**`RetrieveAPIView`** <sup>[drf-doc]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveapiview):

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework.generics import RetrieveAPIView


class ProductDetailView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(
            self.get_queryset(),
            category__slug=self.kwargs['category_slug'],
            slug=self.kwargs['product_slug'],
        )
```

Comment: i've gotten the data to be printed in the command line. however, i'm using vue.js for the front end. how do i iterate over the list of fey features for one product and display it to the user? before asking the question in general, i tried using the normal method of iterating through a list in django but that didn't work out

Comment: @Ajirirkariiyelobu: but why do you need to enumerate over the list in Django? It is serialized in the JSON blob, so likely your vue part is not rendering it (correctly).

Comment: how do i edit the get function in the producDetail view so that it can correctly render it on the vue frontend? currently, the data is printed in the terminal as this: <QuerySet [<KeyFeature: 24 hour battery life>, <KeyFeature: works with Apple and Android devices>]>, and it's rendered on the front end like this: [ { "id": 3, "name": "24 hour battery life" }, { "id": 4, "name": "works with Apple and Android devices" } ]

Comment: With a `v-for="key_feature of item.key_features"` with `item` the product you are rendering.

Comment: thanks so much for your help. it all renders correctly now